# How can I make kittens-game run while not using that tab?

Tags: kittens-game

Let's say I'm doing homework on my PC, and I want to earn stuff in kittens-game legit, but the game doesn't let me. It says I have to be on the same tab for me to get any rewards. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Comment: Use Chrome. On Chrome it has no problem running happily in a tab. (With the web worker option selected.)

Comment: You can also open another window where you open the game

Comment: I never had luck, even in Chrome with the Web Worker option selected. I created a new Window Ctrl + N and loaded it there. Even if I wasn't using that window, things worked fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many browser games do not run while you're in another tab.  While Kittens Game has a "web worker" option to allow it work in inactive tabs, I've had poor results with it.  Instead, a work-around I've often used to great effect is to **run the game in a separate *window*.**  In Firefox, this can be easily done by right clicking the tab and choosing Move to New Window.  Other browsers should work very similarly.

Answer (score 11):

Click on `Options` and select `Use web worker (game works correctly in background tab, may cause performance issues)`

Depending on what browsers you have available another option would be to run the game in a separate window, or failing that a browser other than the one you normally use. So if you usually use Firefox, having it running in Chrome it should still progress even if Chrome is minimized.

If you do decided to run the game in another browser, you should be able to export your game and load it using the Export and Import functions from the `Options` menu.

Comment: The performance on this has gotten better, at least in the current version (9.9.5 as of this comment).